# Mysql order column and not null

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql table looks like

```
ID C1 R1 R2
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  NULL    
3  1  1  2 
4  1  1  3
5  1  2  NULL
6  1  2  4
```

I want to retrieve the rows with C1 ID of 1 and after that sort by R1 ascending and first get the NULL value and after that ascending R2.

So my results would be:

```
ID C1 R1 R2
1  1  1  NULL
2  1  1  1    
3  1  1  2 
4  1  1  3
5  1  2  NULL
6  1  2  4
```

Select * from Table t where t.C1 = 1 ......
How can I make my sql query to do what I want?

Comment: `order by R1, R2`

Comment: Is that ID column part of the table or not? Very confusing.

Comment: All C1s are 1, so you can ignore that requirement altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Below query will work:

```
select * from table_name where C1=1 order by R1, R2 ASC
```

Comment: Younghwa was a bit earlier, but thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

select * from table1 where c1=1 order by r1, r2

Comment: @Urban In which case your question (desired result) is wrong.